# how to get a variable's value from Script Task in ssis

Tags: ssis, script-task

I have this code below in one of my Script Tasks in SSIS:

```
       public void Main()
        {
           string filename;


        filename = Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString();

         string getEmployerId = filename.Split('_')[0];

   int employerId = Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(getEmployerId, 
        @"\d+").Value);
          int fail = 1;
```

I need to get the `employerId` value from this code and store it as an variable in my SSIS package.

Does anyone know what would be the best way possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, you are retrieving the EmployerId from the file name, correct? If yes, you don't need to use a script task. Just create a new variable and set an expression to parse the EmployerId. If you can provide the file name, I can help with the expression.

**Update**

Based on the variable character length and the inability to change the file name to include another delimiter, you will need to handle this in a script task by using regex. See the weblink below:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22194.use-ssis-variables-and-parameters-in-a-script-task.aspx

*In the control flow:*

1. Create a filename variable of type string that is set by the for each loop enumerator
2. Create a EmployerID variable of type int32

*In the script task:*

3. Select the filename as read-only and EmployerID as read-write
4. Get the filename value
5. Use your regex to get the EmployeID
6. Set the EmployerID variable

Comment: I have several files and an example would be 'Dem323_04265.45.23.4',Pay661_a454',. In first example employerId is 323 and in second example is 661. The employerId is aloways located before '_'.

Comment: Based on the Regex you have provided, the EmployerID is always decimal, correct? What are the min and max values? Additionally, what is the min max values for the data before the EmployerId (e.g., 'DEM','PAY')?

Comment: Min value for data before EmployerId can be two letters and max would be five and employerId shouldn't be decimal

Comment: Variable character length will make the expression nasty. Before we ditch expressions, can you add an '_' between the data before the EmployerID?

Comment: Nope, I have more than 1000 files in this folder and I'm getting new files every day,  so I can't change file names of all of them. Is there any other possibility to do this? I thought about doing an expression, but it seems too complicated